# Apply css rule if menu is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change the colour of the hamburger icon if the menu is open.

I am not 100% sure how to do this? I assume you would check to see if the 'active' class is there and then if it returns true, execute the css code.

Here is the link to the site: http://plc.fluxeddigitalclients.co.uk/

```
<body>

<div class="page-transition">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <!-- end layer --> 
</div>
<!-- end page-transition -->
<nav class="site-navigation">
  <div class="layer"></div>
  <!-- end layer -->
  <div class="inner">
    <ul data-splitting>
      <li><a href="/">Maison</a> <small>Retour au début</small></li>
      <li><a href="/">Le Tournoi</a> <small>A propos de l'événement</small></li>
      <li><a href="studio.html">Les Joueurs</a> <small>All About Us</small> </li>
      <li><a href="showcases.html">Le Site</a> <small>Our all projects</small> </li>
      <li><a href="blog.html">Media</a> <small>Recent posts</small> </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Galerie</a> <small>Say hello</small> </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Pro AM</a> <small>Say hello</small> </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Partenaires</a> <small>Say hello</small> </li>
       <li><a href="/contact">Pro AM</a> <small>Contact</small> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- end inner --> 
</nav>
<!-- end site-navigation -->
<div class="social-media">
  <div class="layer"> </div>
  <!-- end layer -->
  <div class="inner">
    <h5>Social Share </h5>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#"><i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end social-media -->
<div class="all-cases">
  <div class="layer"> </div>
  <!-- end layer -->
  <div class="inner">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html#">Darkness</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">Goddes</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">Employee</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">Berry</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">Roosters</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html#">Primero</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- end inner --> 
</div>
<!-- end all-cases -->
<main>
  <aside class="left-side">
    <div class="logo"> <a href="index.html"><img src="/themes/paris-legends-championship/assets/images/branding/paris-legends-icon.png" alt="Image"></a> </div>
    <!-- end logo -->
    <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger">
      <div class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--01">
        <div class="hamburger__line-in hamburger__line-in--01"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--02">
        <div class="hamburger__line-in hamburger__line-in--02"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--03">
        <div class="hamburger__line-in hamburger__line-in--03"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--cross01">
        <div class="hamburger__line-in hamburger__line-in--cross01"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hamburger__line hamburger__line--cross02">
        <div class="hamburger__line-in hamburger__line-in--cross02"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end hamburger -->
    <div class="follow-us"> FOLLOW US </div>
    <!-- end follow-us -->
    <div class="equalizer">
        <a href="" class="jf__link" target="_blank">
            <img src="/themes/paris-legends-championship/assets/images/jf.png" class="img-fluid jf__link--img" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <!-- end equalizer --> 
  </aside>
  <!-- end left-side -->
  <div class="all-cases-link"> <span>Leaderboard</span> <b><i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i></b> </div>
  <!-- end all-cases-link -->
```

here is the current css

```
.hamburger__line-in::after, .hamburger__line-in::before {
    width: 60px;
    height: 2px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

and I want to change it to

```
.hamburger__line-in::after, .hamburger__line-in::before {
    width: 60px;
    height: 2px;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #C1A473;
}
```

I would appreciate anyones solution.

Comment: please add css as well

Comment: Where does the click event go? Cant you register/listen to the click event and use that event.target that gets passed in the callback to mutate/add the class to the DOM element? also are you using jquery - looks like there are other things changing the class name when its clicked. I wonder if you can edit that code doing that - otherwise heres a shorty for you $('#hamburger').click(function(e) {
 $(e.target).toggleClass('open');
})

Comment: As Naga says, CSS is key. Changing the hover state on the "hamburger" will allow you to modify it as you describe here.

Comment: just add `.active { color: #yourcolor; }` after the initial burger styles, once the element receives the active class, it will get the new styles.

Comment: Im not very familiar with JS to be honest. I have added the css to the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you could use jQuery or just JS to change the CSS properties, or, since there's already a class that toggles based on opened/closed, you can just style child elements based on that class with pure CSS (you might want to handle states too, like hover):

```
.hamburger.is-opened-navi .hamburger__line.hamburger__line--cross01 *::after,
.hamburger.is-opened-navi .hamburger__line.hamburger__line--cross02 *::after {
    background-color: #122e1A;
}
```

Testing, it seems to work better with the `::before` and `::after`:

```
.hamburger.is-opened-navi .hamburger__line.hamburger__line--cross01 *::before,
.hamburger.is-opened-navi .hamburger__line.hamburger__line--cross02 *::before,
.hamburger.is-opened-navi .hamburger__line.hamburger__line--cross01 *::after,
.hamburger.is-opened-navi .hamburger__line.hamburger__line--cross02 *::after {
    background-color: #122e1A;
}
```

Edit: A nice dark green suits the site better than a solid red.

For the "follow-us" link, which I didn't even see at first (with Ad Block Plus), it's a better candidate for jQuery, since it doesn't have any ancestors whose class changes when the menu is opened. For that, you could define a CSS class for when it is active:

```
.follow-us.active {
    color: #C1A473;
}
```

And add a quick click listener that changes its active class (put it at the end of the body, in a `<script></script>` just before the `</body>` tag):

```
$('.hamburger').click(function() {
  $('.follow-us').toggleClass('active');  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that mark! You legend!

How could I do it for the other item in the side nav i.e Follow Us?

Comment: Aw Shucks. Edited.

Comment: @JakeFeeley - one more suggestion, add `transition: color 1.5s;` to the CSS rules for `.follow-us` (or `.left-side.follow-us` since you already have those rules specified) - not every browser will respect it, but Chrome will - there's probably other versions of `transition` that'll work for color for different browsers, too, but I verified that one in Chrome. If you found the answer useful, be sure to mark it as the correct answer so others can find it and so no one wastes time resolving something that's resolved. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really "execute" CSS. You just set up rules that apply styles based on what selectors are present. Right now it looks like your `.active` class gets applied to a different container than the one that holds the hamburger. If you instead apply it to a parent of both the current place it's applied and the hamburger, then you could write a rule that changes both things when `.active` is applied. Or alternatively, you could apply `.active` to multiple places, meaning in addition to where it's currently being applied, also apply it to the parent of the hamburger.